# ASP.NET Object Error using ClipboardActiveX.dll

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

I've been ask to do a pasting an copied image from clipboard to Web Form and directly upload in web server. I've found some [TUTORIAL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25967/Clipboard-ActiveX-for-Image-Copy-Paste-into-Web-Fo)! about it, But its been dead for almost 4 years, I need someone to guide me, Im new in programming im currently taking my Internship as a programmer of php.

I could paste the image from Clipboard to Web Form, But when i start uploading it onto the server, i got this error "Object Required". I can't seem find a way to fix it.

```
  function uplImages() {
      flagUploadingStarted = true;

      // Uploading Image 1 if its present.
      if (document.getElementById("<%= hdnImageFileName1.ClientID%>").value != "") {
          uploadImage1(document.getElementById("<%= hdnImageFileName1.ClientID%  >").value); // Error get here "OBJECT REQUIRED".
      }
  }
```